# actionlink manipulates html render order in nested anchor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm having a problem and i'm really puzzled by it.

My markup is simple enough:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <a class="mapIconUnit" id="pinDelete-@item.PinGuid.ToString()">
        @Url.Action("DeletePin") <!-- testing purposes -->
        @(Ajax.ActionLink("x", "DeletePin", MapAdministrationController.Routes.DeletePin(item.PinGuid), new AjaxOptions()
            {
                OnSuccess = "onMapPinDeleted",
                Confirm = Resources.Resource.msg_GenericDeleteConfirmationQuestion
            }
        ))
    </a>
}
```

Now what i would expect to render from this is:

```
<a class="mapIconUnit" id="...">
    ... rendered url
    <a href="..." etc>x</a>
</a>
```

But what i am getting is:

```
<a class="mapIconUnit" id="...">
    ... rendered url
</a>
<a href="..." etc>x</a>
```

What am i doing wrong here? The markup is too simple for it to be wrong to cause such a  thing?

Comment: You can't put an `<a>` element inside an `<a>` element, so either razor or your browser fixes it.

Comment: really does seem to be related to nested anchor elements. thinking about it, it makes sense too. how would the browser know which href to follow when you could technically click while hovering 2 elements at the same time. guess i'll have to change my markup then. thanks for your assistance

Comment: @Marthijn if you change your comment to an answer i'll accept it. Since it was the correct indication on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's illegal to nest an anchor element inside another anchor element, more info can be found in the W3C specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

`Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.`

So either razor or the webbrowser renders the elements correctly (i.e. place them next to each other).